# Localhost Express works but Nginx proxy_pass gives a 404 sometimes

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Typically I am quick to find my own nginx config issues, but I am unsure about this one...

I have made an API Endpoint that is used to call a SQL Request from an external system. I know the query works because when I run it in localhost it does fine.

The process goes as follows:

Reactjs App makes the call to {someURL}/SQLRequest/:connectionId/:query

the query url param is scrubbed before it gets sent out as well as passed into encodeURI(query) to be URL safe.

When it reaches the API it goes through and runs the query and returns the result set.

===========The Problem in Depth============
When I am running my React App Locally as well as having my API which is NodeJS and express running locally the query runs perfectly and the charts and scalar value widgets in the app display properly.

When I go ahead and build the API (I use pkg) and the deploy it to the server in AWS (using Ubuntu at the moment) the SQLRequest sometimes just doesn't work.
The server uses nginx to provide the webserver. I know that my proxy_pass is fine because every other API call in the entire application runs fine.

If I run the API endpoint on a small query such as select 1; it runs fine. If I do something a little longer such as SELECT TOP 1 myValue FROM myTable it works but the moment I start doing anything more complex it gives me a 404 not found error.

========Troubleshooting Steps I've Taken=========
Initially I thought that maybe I had some issue with my deployed web application so I just changed my localhost UI to look at the deployed API and everything but the longer queries worked fine still.

I then thought it was something to do with the length and it still may be but in my googling I found a post that recommended adding
`client_header_buffer_size 128k; large_client_header_buffers 16 128k;` 
to allow for longer URLs this did not work for me but I may be missing something.

I then began to wonder about the proxy_pass and so I ran a curl in the linux terminal for the server and did my localhost:port with the query that was originally failing and it worked perfectly and returned the data set.

I am unsure what to do next. I will also include my nginx configuration below. If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {


        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        keepalive_timeout 65;


        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;


        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        gzip on;

        server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name default_server;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 25M;

        client_header_buffer_size 64k;
        large_client_header_buffers 16 128k;

        location /api/ {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
        }

        location /api/public/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3010/;
        }

        location /util/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }

        location / {

                root /var/www/mydemo;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        }

}
}
```

Any changes to the nginx configuration is also welcome as I have only really been using it for the last year or so.